# Catching a runtime error from a vector input, displaying the row number c++

Tags: c++, class, vector, try-catch

i created my own class "ClosedIntegral" which is a simple way to define an integral with the two limits, creating a runtime_error when the lower limit is bigger than the upper, which works.
I know wanna import a few members of my class, which are stored in a text file, into a vector, and if one of them triggers the runtime error, i wanna catch it, ignore it, and then print out the rownumber that has been ignored. However i cant access my vector from within the catch function, and i dont know how to fix that..

So here is my code

```
        class ClosedInterval {
public:
ClosedInterval (double x1 = 0., double x2 = 0.) : lower {x1}, upper {x2} 
{}

double length(ClosedInterval) const
{return upper - lower;}

private: 

double lower, upper;

 friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, const ClosedInterval& x)
    {
        out  << '[' << x.lower <<  ", " << x.upper << "] Length of "<<x.length(x);
        return out;
    }


};


istream& operator>>(istream& is, ClosedInterval& c)
{   
    double a, b;
    is  >> a >> b;
   if (a>b)
        throw runtime_error{"Lower limit is bigger than upper limit "};
     else
        c = ClosedInterval{a,b};
    return is;
}



int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) 
{   

string fname = (argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "input.txt");
    ifstream ifs{fname};  
    if (!ifs.is_open())
        throw runtime_error{"cannot open input file " + fname};  

 try{
 vector<ClosedInterval> integrals;

    for (ClosedInterval f; ifs >> f; )
        integrals.push_back(f);

}

catch (const runtime_error& error)
{
  cout<<"Row ignored.";
}
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Has it occurred to you to put only what throws the exception, just the >> operator, inside try/catch, instead of everything?

Comment: Also consider leaving it uncaught and run the program in your development environment's debugger. It should stop the program and allow you to investigate more closely (stack traces, state of the variables in play, etc...) Very handy tool, the debugger.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I did, but it only works if i put the whole loop inside. My major problem is, that after the runtime_error catch, it stops reading my input file..

Comment: I'm confident that putting only the >> operator inside the try/catch block will work just fine. There is no requirement in C++ to put only entire for loops inside try/catch blocks.